# PGFplots: Can I do vector addition/substraction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like, in the following MWE, to draw a vector from `P` to `P+v` and to `P-v` for some given point `P` and directional vector `v` in the **axis coordinate system** of a `pgfplot`. Can it be done?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis equal,
  xmin=-4,
  xmax=4,
  ymin=-4,
  ymax=4,
]

\coordinate (P) at (axis cs:2,1);

\draw[->] (P) -- (axis cs:2+1,1+1); % P+v
\draw[->] (P) -- (axis cs:2-1,1-1); % P-v

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is being done in a `pgfplot` due to additional plotting commands that aren't shown.

**Edit:** From the manual, chapter 4.17:

> This means, in particular, that
>   adding two points has unexpected effects: the expression (`axis cs:0,0) ++ (axis cs:1,0)` is not
>   necessarily the same as `(axis cs:1,0)`.

Comment: I don't understand your question... this MWE compiles and shows the two "vectors". What are you asking?

Comment: @darthbith In TikZ parlance I'd like to do `(P) -- ++(v)`

Comment: What is `v`? How is it defined? Did you try to do just what you wrote? If I recall, in the most recent version of pgfplots, the default coordinate system is the `axis cs`. You should add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` to your preamble

Comment: @darthbith Well, obviously `v=(1,1)`. I just set `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` which changed exactly nothing: If I omit `axis cs:`, no vector is drawn, and if I leave it and try some math, it will draw arrows of wrong length or direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `axis direction cs`, described in section 4.17 of the [`pgfplots` v 1.11 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). I have also used the `calc` `tizklibrary` in this MWE. The `calc` library is necessary to be able to do the subtraction. Moreover, as I suggested in a comment to the question, the `axis cs` on the definition of `P` is not required in v1.11.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis equal,
  xmin=-4,
  xmax=4,
  ymin=-4,
  ymax=4,
]

\coordinate (P) at (2,1);
\coordinate (v) at (axis direction cs:1,1);

\draw[->] (P) -- ($(P)+(v)$); % P+v
\draw[->] (P) -- ($(P)-(v)$); % P-v
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn! You had it 7 minutes faster. I still had to use `(axis cs:2,1)` and will therefore now update my TeX packages.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)